# Swfaddress and IE8

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, swfaddress

Has anyone successfully gotten swfaddress to work with IE8 and above?

It seems that when using standards mode, swfaddress will appear to work fine in IE8 and IE9, however, once the user modifies the hashtag in the address bar, the history list becomes corrupted.

In cases where the user starts the application via the hash tag (http://myapp.com/#/test), and then visits another hash (http://myapp.com/#/test1), the history is never saved.

I have tried playing around with [swfaddress 2.5](http://swfaddress.svn.sourceforge.net/) in the svn repository. Interestingly, 
the code is similiar to [JQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) (by the same author). I also note that JQuery Address suffers from the same problem.

If I turn on compatibility mode in IE, the swfaddress and JQuery Address works perfectly. I have been looking into how compatiblilty mode works, and it does not seem like it would modify or affect javascript execution.

Was anyone able to successfully solve this issue? If not are there any other deep linking libraries for flex or flash that contains all the feature sets of swfaddress?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have built a workaround for this sometime. Also GWT apps handle this nicely. I will look into it later.

Comment: I checked some of my live stuff and it turns out that I also have the same bug. :/.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know:) I am assuming there's something in IE8 and IE9 that breaks the functionality required. I have tested using IE9 on a Win 7 machine with all the latest updates as well as IE8 under XP mode with the latest updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at libraries such JQuery Address, other JQuery state management plugins and even the `BrowserManager` that ships with Flash and Flex builder, I discovered that they all ran into the same issue as SwfAddress.

At the moment, SwfAddress offers that best features and comes with a .swc and .as files to easily interface with Flash and Flex applications.

Since the other javascript libraries ended up with the same problems, I have decided to stick with SwfAddress.

On a related note, the author has stated that he is no longer working on SwfAddress, so it would be cool if someone in the community can pick up on where it was left off.